# Rails with Aptana studio IDE configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Aptana studio IDE for my rails project. I mapped the installed location of rails path  to the IDE like we usually map the java class path to netbeans . But when i execute a command

```
bundle install
```

In windows command prompt it gives me an error.but when i run the same in IDE terminal view it perfectly works . What is the reason . Is rails designed only to work with linux and Mac or something else . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the same problem occurred to me once.when i posted the problem in aptana website all i got is rails is primarily designed to work with linux.so you should get used to work with the ide's linux terminal view.